# The integral of a Gaussian process on a unit sphere

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-matrices

Suppose there exist a zero-mean Gaussian process $\mathbb{G} f_u$ indexed by $u \in \mathcal{S}^{p - 1}$ with known covariance $\mathrm{E} \big[ \mathbb{G} f_u \mathbb{G} f_v \big]$ when both $u$ and $v$ are known, where $\mathcal{S}^{p - 1}$ is the $p$-dimensional unit sphere. Now I want to know what exactly the integral
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{\mathcal{S}^{p - 1}} \, \mathbb{G} f_u \, du
\end{equation*}
is. This is a integral Gaussian process on the unit sphere. I try my best to find some articles about it, but I cannot find any useful information about it.

Does anyone can help me with how to handle this integral or know some literature about this integral? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\newcommand{\bG}{\mathbb{G}}$ $\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}$
$$
X=\int_S \bG f_u du,\;\;k(u,v)=\bE( \bG f_u \bG f_v).
$$
Then $X$ is a mean zero Gaussian random variable so it suffices to find its variance $\bE(X^2)$.  Note that
$$
X^2=\int_{S\times S} \bG f_u\bG f_v dudv
$$
so
$$
\bE(X^2)= \int_{S\times S} \bE(\bG f_u\bG f_v) dudv=\int_{S\times S} k(u,v) dudv.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems like a fantastic solution! Does there some theories to guarantee this?

Comment: Use Bochmer integrals to justify this. In fact  one needs a thepry of integration of Banach valued functions to give a meaning to $$ \int_S \mathbb{G} f_u du. $$

Comment: Thank you so much! I have never touched these fantastic things before. Could you recommend some good textbooks or papers regarding these things for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the Chapter V  of the book  *Functional Analysis*  by K. Yosida

Comment: I appreciate your generous help!